# Insert block before footer in single page cms

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, layout-update, cms-pages

I need to insert a block before the footer in single page cms (magento 1.9).

I tried to do it by using layout.

I have added below code in my layout file :

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="latte_asina_footer" before="-" >  
           <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>latte-asina-footer</block_id></action>  
    </block>
</reference>
```

but it is not working.

can you help me?

Comment: before footer ? what you mean by single page cms

Comment: in a specific page i what to insert, after the main content, a block. between main content and footer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the identifier of the static block you want to call is **`latte-asina-footer`**, please follow below steps to call the block on particular CMS page footer only.

- Go to **`CMS -> Pages`** and open the particular page, in which you want to call the static block.
- Click on **`Design`** tab and put below XML in the Custom Layout Update XML section textarea.

[image: call custom static block in particular cms page in footer]

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="custom-footer" before="-" >
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>custom-footer</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

- Save the page and flush Magento cache before trying to see the changes in the frontend.

Comment: not work for me

Comment: It has been tested in Magento 1.9.3.2 and working fine for me. Please refresh Magento cache and retest.

Comment: Same not working, Can you please let me know what was the code for 1.9.39?